# How to find and update node properties in neo4j to a new text

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

In my NEO4J DB, I am looking to write a query that will find all the properties of the nodes that contain a substring and update that substring.

I.E :

I have 10000 nodes like:

```
CREATE (n:Person {name: 'andyLovesNEO4J', title: 'NEO4J.BLAH'})
```

but the property names are all different.
I want to find the properties that contain 'NEO4J' and update that value to 'SQL' corresponding to them. Basically, update the strings that contain that substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND keys(properties(p)) AS keys
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(p, keys, replace(p[keys], 'NEO4J', 'SQL'))
YIELD node
RETURN DISTINCT node
```

Fetch the nodes, unwind the property keys, and then set the new value for the property using `apoc.create.setProperty`.

If you want to find the required nodes, and only update the necessary keys, try this:

```
MATCH (p) WHERE ANY (k IN keys(p) WHERE apoc.map.get(properties(p),k) CONTAINS 'NEO4J')
WITH p, [k IN keys(p) WHERE apoc.map.get(properties(p),k) CONTAINS 'NEO4J' | k] as keys
CALL apoc.create.setProperties(p,[k in keys|k], [k in keys | replace(p[k], 'NEO4J', 'SQL')])
YIELD node
RETURN node;
```

Here, we have removed the Person label, so that every node is checked, and we filter and keep the relevant properties. I am using the `setProperties` function as suggested by jose_bacoy, in his answer, to avoid unnecessary complexity.

Comment: So there are many nodes of different labels, not all of them are of type Person. And not all properties need to be updated. I need to find which properties need to be updated as well

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Charchit, you can use this APOC function BUT without using UNWIND.
You can update the properties as a list of keys and values inside the APOC function.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p, keys(p) AS keys
CALL apoc.create.setProperties(p,[k in keys|k], [k in keys | replace(p[k], 'NEO4J', 'SQL')])
YIELD node
RETURN node;
```

Comment: How would I find the properties first? Because in the node there might be several properties that need to be updated, not all of them. And there are different types of nodes i.e cat, dog etc